# Nodejs: how to change node version with nvm while using child_process's spawn

Tags: node.js, spawn, nvm

I used spawn to run a script, but the script needs node8.x while my default version is 6.

so, how to change node version with nvm while using child_process's spawn

```js
let linkstart = ()=>{
    let cp = spawn('node', ['dist/app.js']);

    cp.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.error('stderr: ', data.toString('utf8'));
    })

    cp.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.info('stdout: ', data.toString('utf8'));
    })

    return cp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're running .js file. you need to use process.fork

```
let setup = {
  execPath : '/home/User/.nvm/v8.7.0/bin/node' ,   // path to binary
  cwd: Path to dist/
  stdio : [0, 1, 2, 'ipc']       // [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr, ipc]
}

let fork = require('child_process').fork;
let child = fork('app.js', setup);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code, to call a script function, which in-turn switches the shell's node version (using nvm), then calls the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

nvm use v8.7.0
node dist/app.js
```

I tried to do something like

```
let cp = spawn('nvm', ['use', 'v8.7.0', ';', 'node', 'dist/app.js']);
```

But it gives the following error

```
Error: spawn nvm ENOENT
```

On, digging further on it, seems we cannot call `nvm` directly from any node script, reasoning for it is given here @[Github](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/540). I'll try looking further down if any other possible solution exists :)

Hope this helps!